# Orientation change with multiple fragments and different layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, orientation

In landscape, I have an activity with previewFragment loaded into the R.id.fragment_container_child (on the left third of the screen) and selectionFragment loaded into R.id.fragment_container_parent (right two thirds of the screen). Selecting the second tab changes selectionFragment to contactFragment but previewFragment remains the same. This all works fine.
Upon an orientation change, the layout is changed slightly via xml, where R.id.fragment_child now occupies the bottom third, instead of the left third. The problem arises when I change the orientation. My action bar and fragments disappear, although the layout is confirmed changing.
I have not defined `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the Manifest file. Below is the code to my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

static SelectionFragment selectionFragment;
static ContactFragment contactFragment;
public static PreviewFragment previewFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container_child) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        previewFragment = new PreviewFragment();
        selectionFragment = new SelectionFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container_child, previewFragment,
                "PREVIEW");
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container_parent, selectionFragment,
                "SELECTION");
        transaction.commit();
    }
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.menu)
            .setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(R.string.client_information).setTabListener(this));
    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
    case 0:
        if (selectionFragment == null) {
            selectionFragment = new SelectionFragment();
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container_parent,
                    selectionFragment, "SELECTION");
        } else {
            transaction.attach(selectionFragment);
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (contactFragment == null) {
            contactFragment = new ContactFragment();
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container_parent,
                    contactFragment, "CONTACT");
        } else {
            transaction.attach(contactFragment);
        }
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
    case 0:
        if (selectionFragment != null)
            transaction.detach(selectionFragment);
        break;
    case 1:
        if (contactFragment != null)
            transaction.detach(contactFragment);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand what really happens to you, but here some tips:

- When you rotate the screen Android destroy and rebuild all Fragment/Activity. So take a look in your onCreate, onDestroy...
- If you're want a multiple screen app take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and create new layouts for each screen to make sure that your app will work fine.